# Corrosion rate of aluminium

Tags: electrochemistry, corrosion

In which conditions the corrosion rate of aluminium is faster?

a) acidic conditions
b) neutral
c) alkaline conditions

I know that corrosion can be in a and c cases but I dont know when it'll be faster. Also please describe why corrosion rate in one case is faster than in other one.

Comment: Not your fault, but this problem you were given is incompetently formulated and simply lacks details to be answered adequately. Well, at least they wrote aluminium, not aluminum.

Answer (score 1):

In general, corrosion rate **depends** on too many factors. Which acid or base, which concentration, which temperature? Which other chemical species are present? Is there [galvanic corrosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_corrosion) present? Is there a voltage applied, and which voltage? And so on.

How do you even you measure the "rate" of corrosion: depth per unit time, mass per unit time, other? Both may depend on surface geometry, defects, etc. If you measure as mass per unit time, that depends on how finely the material is divided, since corrosion occurs at the surface. More finely divided -> more surface. Depth per unit time [may not even be uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitting_corrosion) across the whole sample.

This applies not only to aluminum.

Assuming you keep all other factors the same, you still need to specify at least the type of acid or base, and their concentration. For example, aluminum [won't dissolve in concentrated nitric acid](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/145349/103633).